# How to access hash from object

Tags: perl, oop

I have written a small class which just got some getter and setter methods. One of those Properties is a hash.

```
sub getMyData
{
    my $objekt = shift;
    return $objekt->{MYDATA};
}

sub setMyData
{
    my $objekt = shift;
    my %myData= shift;

    $objekt->{MYDATA} = \%myData;
}
```

If i set the value like this in another skript which access my class:

```
my %test;
$test{'apple'}='red';

$objekt = MYNAMESPACE::MYCLASS->new;
$objekt->setMyData(%test);
```

I thought i can access this value easy via:

```
my $data = $objekt->getMyData;
print $data{'apple'};
```

I just get undef value.

Output from Dumper:
[image]

Can someone tell me what's wrong here and how i can access getMyData and print the value 'red'?

Comment: You're sending `('apple', 'red')` to `setMyData`. That probably isn't what you want to do. You might mean `setMyData(\%test)`. But usually when using objects, you don't pass hashes back and forth, but rather use a `get_data_value('apple')` method.

Comment: The names in your code are horrible. German variable names are ok if that works for you, but there are some best practices you should follow. In Perl OOP, the object is usually called `$self`. All-caps names like `MYDATA` are usually used for constants only (but those are used rarely). The Perl-world prefers to name variables and functions not in CamelCase, but instead use underscores, like `set_my_data`. Besides that, you should take a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: You are accessing %data, not $data.  `use strict;` should be at the top of your code to prevent using undeclared variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the dereference arrow. Because you put a hashref (`\%myData`) in, you also get a reference out.

```
my $data = $objekt->getMyData;
print $data->{'apple'};
#          ^
#          here
```

You also need to change the assignment, because you are passing a list to the setter, not a reference. `shift` is for scalar (single) values, but `%test` gets turned into a list (many values).

```
sub setMyData
{
    my $objekt = shift;
    my %myData = @_;

    $objekt->{MYDATA} = \%myData;
}
```

However, there are a few more issues with your code.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue. Furthermore i will rename all variables and methods to the perl standard.

Answer (score 4):

[`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) removes and returns the *first* element of an array. Inside of a subroutine a bare shift operates on `@_`, which contains a copy of all arguments passed to that subroutine.

What is really happening here is that `setMyData` is being passed this data:

```
setMyData($objekt, 'apple', 'red');
```

1. The first `shift` in `setMyData` removes `$objekt` from `@_`
2. The second `shift` in `setMyData` removes 'apple', but since you assign the result of this shift to a Hash it creates a Hash that looks like this: `'apple' => undef`
3. You take a reference to this Hash and store it in the MYDATA key of `$objekt`

What you really want is to assign the remainder of `@_` to your Hash:

```
sub setMyData {
    my $objekt = shift;
    my %myData = @_;
    # my ($objekt, %myData) = @_; (alternative)

    $objekt->{MYDATA} = \%myData;
}
```

Another option is to instead send a Hash reference to `setMyData`, which *would* work with `shift`:

```
sub setMyData {
    my $objekt = shift;
    my $myData_ref = shift

    $objekt->{MYDATA} = $myData_ref;
}
$objekt->setMyData(\%test);
```

Comment: You're still missing the `->` because the getter returns a ref.

Comment: @simbabque I left that out because you already addressed it :)